# How to create a named url for Django documentation created using Sphinx

Tags: django, python-sphinx

In my Django project I created a rudimentary documentation using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/). Now what I wanted to test was calling the documentation index page (`index.html`) as I would for a standard Django view using **named url**.

I have been browsing for quite a while but it seems that without some 3rd party app (such as *django-docs*) it is not possible to create the scenario (*I hope I am wrong*). I am trying to avoid using a hardcoded link for the purpose.

**Is there a way I may call the documentation from anywhere in my Django app using a dynamic link (preferably using a shortcut)?**